# How to convert a grid-like matplotlib plot to a smooth gradient like surface?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a 2D numpy array using `imshow` function from `matplotlib.pyplot` (it is the plot of a U-matrix generated using the codebook of a self organizing map).

The plot is being generated by the following line:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(umat, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r'), alpha=1)
```

Here, umat is the 2D numpy array that I am trying to plot. Here is the plot that is generated:

[image]

It shows each node (point) as a distinct square.

I would like to generate something like this

[image],

showing a smooth surface, however I am unable to find a way to do it. Could someone show how it could be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use imshow, you can try different interpolation methods, see https://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html

Example:
 `ax.imshow(grid, interpolation=interp_method, cmap='viridis')`
where `interp_method` is one of

```
methods = [None, 'none', 'nearest', 'bilinear', 'bicubic', 'spline16', 'spline36', 'hanning', 'hamming', 'hermite', 'kaiser', 'quadric', 'catrom', 'gaussian', 'bessel', 'mitchell', 'sinc', 'lanczos']
```

Comment: Thanks. This is just what I was looking for. Could you suggest a good starting point for learning plotting?

Comment: I find the examples on the matplotlib website quite instructive, however this is not course or something like that. https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html

Comment: I have seen the gallery earlier but TIL the plots have links to the code. Thanks!